# Backbone.js Routing failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

**UPDATED**

I need run the index function for index.html .I did everything the Router wanted to do for run the functions at index.html .This is my Router.js .I wanna run the index:function() and print the "Hello World" string on index.html .The purpose of doing this connecting router.js to index.html . If i doing this, i will progress for my project with new functions.I hope i could tell.

Thanks For answering

```
    define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'handlebars',
    'spin',
    'app/models/LoginModel',
    'app/collections/InformationCollection',
    'app/collections/TravelCollection',
    'app/collections/UserRegisterCollection',
    'app/collections/UserSearchCollection',
    'app/views/LoginView',
    'app/views/UserRegisterView'
], function ($,
             _,
             Backbone,
             Handlebars,
             Spinner,
             Login,
             Informations,
             Travels,
             UserRegister,
             UserSearch,
             LoginView,
             UserRegisterViews
) {


    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

        routes: {
            'search': 'search',
            'login': 'login',
            'travels': 'travels',
            'user': 'user',
            'menu': 'menu',
            '':'index'
        },

        index:function(){

            $(document.body).append("Hello World!..");
        },
```

And this is my main.js

```
 require.config({

    baseUrl: "resources",
    waitSeconds: 100,
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'lib/jquery-1.9.1',
        'bootstrap': 'lib/bootstrap',
        'html5shiv': 'lib/html5shiv',
        'spin': 'lib/spin',
        'respond': 'lib/respond',
        'underscore': 'lib/underscore',
        'backbone': 'lib/backbone',
        'handlebars': 'lib/handlebars-v3.0.3',
        'template': 'app/templates'
    },
    shim: {
        html5shiv: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        respond: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        bootstrap: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        jquery: {
            exports: '$'
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        handlebars: {
            exports: "Handlebars"
        }
    },
    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime()
});

require([
    'jquery',
    'bootstrap',
    'html5shiv',
    'respond',
    'util',
    'spin',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'handlebars',
    'app/Router'
], function ($,
             $,
             $,
             $,
             util,
             Spinner,
             _,
             Backbone,
             Handlebars,
             Router) {
    var Router = new Router();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

And i runned the project.index.html just clear page with no "Hello World".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate the router and then call `Backbone.history.start()`

```
var router = new Router();
Backbone.history.start();
```

From docs:

> During page load, after your application has finished creating all of its routers, be sure to call `Backbone.history.start()` or `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})` to route the initial URL.